# Storing large, session-level datasets?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, web-applications, search

I'm working on building a web application that consists of users doing the following:

1. Browse and search against a Solr server containing millions of entries.  (This part of the app is working really well.)
2. Select a privileged piece of this data (the results of some particular search), and temporarily save it as a "dataset".  (I'd like dataset size to be limited to something *really* large, say half a million results.)
3. Perform some sundry operations on that dataset.

(The frontend's built in Rails, though I doubt that's really relevant to how to solve this particular problem.)

Step two, and how to retrieve the data for step 3, are what's giving me trouble.  I need to be able to temporarily save datasets, recover them when they're needed, and expire them after a while.  The problem is, my results have SHA1 checksum IDs, so each ID is 48 characters.  A 500,000 record dataset, even if I only store IDs, is 22 MB of data.  So I can't just have a single database table and throw a row in it for each dataset that a user constructs.

Has anybody out there ever needed something like this before?  What's the best way to approach this problem?  Should I generate a separate table for each dataset that a user constructs?  If so, what's the best way to expire/delete these tables after a while?  I can deploy a MySQL server if needed (though I don't have one up yet, all the data's in Solr), and I'd be open to some crazier software as well if something else fits the bill.

EDIT: Some more detailed info, in response to Jeff Ferland below.

The data objects are immutable, static, and reside entirely within the Solr database.  It might be more efficient as files, but I would much rather (for reasons of search and browse) keep them where they are.  Neither the data nor the datasets need to be distributed across multiple systems, I don't expect we'll ever get that kind of load.  For now, the whole damn thing runs inside a single VM (I can cross that bridge if I get there).

By "recovering when needed," what I mean is something like this:  The user runs a really carefully crafted search query, which gives them some set of objects as a result.  They then decide they want to manipulate that set.  When they (as a random example) click the "graph these objects by year" button, I need to be able to retrieve the full set of object IDs so I can take them back to the Solr server and run more queries.  I'd rather store the object IDs (and not the search query), because the result set may change underneath the user as we add more objects.

A "while" is roughly the length of a user session.  There's a complication, though, that might matter: I may wind up needing to implement a job queue so that I can defer processing, in which case the "while" would need to be "as long as it takes to process your job."

Thanks to Jeff for prodding me to provide the right kind of further detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First trick: don't represent your SHA1 as text, but rather as the 20 bytes it takes up. The hex value you see is a way of showing bytes in human readable form. If you store them properly, you're at 9.5MB instead of 22.

Second, you haven't really explained the nature of what you're doing. Are your saved datasets references to immutable objects in the existing database? What do you mean by recovering them when needed? How long is "a while" when you talk about expiration? Is the underlying data that you're referencing static or dynamic? Can you save the search pattern and an offset, or do you need to save the individual reference?

Does the data related to a session need to be inserted into a database? Might it be more efficient in files? Does that need to be distributed across multiple systems?

There are a lot of questions left in my answer. For that, you need to better express or even define the requirements beyond the technical overview you've given.

---

**Update**: There are many possible solutions for this. Here are two:

- Write those to a single table (saved_searches or such) that has an incrementing search id. Bonus points for inserting your keys in sorted order. (search_id unsigned bigint, item_id char(20), primary key (search_id, item_id). That will really limit fragmentation, keep each search clustered, and free up pages in a roughly sequential order. It's almost a rolling table, and that's about the best case for doing great amounts of insertions and deletions. In that circumstance, you pay a cost for insertion, and double that cost for deletion. You must also iterate the entire search result.
- If your search items have an incrementing primary id such that any new insertion to the database will have a higher value than anything that is already in the database, that is the most efficient. Alternately, inserting a datestamp would achieve the same effect with less efficiency (every row must actually be checked in a query instead of just the index entries). If you take note of that maximum id, and you don't delete records, then you can save searches that use zero space by always setting a maximum id on the saved query.

Comment: Awesome - thanks!  I hadn't considered that you might get decent throughput with (something resembling) a rolling table.  (Database design, as you can see, is not my forte!)